# Not able to open url in webview

Tags: android, webview

When I load url it shows a window to select browser. For ex. - If I want to open "http://www.facebook.com/" then it show me window to choose chrome or default browser. I am not able to understand why this is happening.

Actually in below code if i successfully got url from server then I hide a sorry image and show webview. Otherwise I show webview and hide sorry image.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            webView.setInitialScale(1);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com/");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to add this line

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

Comment: Thanks it works. But why we add this line. Actually I want to know what happen if we add this line..

Comment: this is an version issue. If you run your app above 3.0 you no need to write this line but when you run app in older version this line do a trick because if you not specify the webview client the browser will be treated as default webclient in older version.If you really like the solution you can upvote also for appreciate the answer.

Comment: make this question as answered ;)

Answer (score 2):

Add a `WebViewClient` like this

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
}
```

You should **override** your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method.

In your UI activity add this line

```
 web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
```

It will solve your problem. Hope it helps!